# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID error randomly

Tags: c#, excel, iis, iis-7.5, dcom

In my application I should generate an excel file from database, I've had encountered this **Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID** error before so after searching I found the solution and fixed it, so I could generated the excel file but now it doesn't work and I should go to:

```
 Component Services -> DCOM Config -> Microsoft Excel Application
```

and right click and go to:

```
properties -> security tab
```

and change everything to **Use Default** and press ok, then It'll be ok again until next time the error happens(happens randomly so far) I should do the same to fix it. Kinda like the settings get reset.

What could be the reason?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using COM automation for office on server is not supported by Microsoft. Even if you get it working somehow you will end up in landing in marshy area of memory leakage. There are some other non COM based solutions to generate excel. Open Office SDK is one of them. I suggest to explore those options.

Comment: @PankajKapare thanks for your reply, the problem is that this excel generation process is created long ago by another programmer and moving it to open office sdk might not be a preferred choice of the company. But thanks again